# oracle to_date function not accepting format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01843

When I do this in oracle 10g:

```
select to_date(trunc(SOMEINPUTdATE)) from table1
where to_date(trunc(date_column_timestamp),'MM/DD/YYYY')
  >= to_date('03/11/2011' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I get: `ORA-01843: not a valid month` if I change to : `'YYYY/MM/DD'`, it works.
But `'MM/DD/YYYY'` is a valid format right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting things mixed up a bit. TO_DATE converts a string into a DATE. If `date_column_timestamp` is already a date, you don't need to convert it to a date.

```
select trunc(SOMEINPUTdATE) from table1
where trunc(date_column_timestamp)
  >= to_date('03/11/2011' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

The `ORA-01843` is caused by the implicit conversion of a date to string. In other words, the following:

```
to_date(trunc(date_column_timestamp),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

is equivalent to (assuming the default date format `DD-MON-YYYY`):

```
to_date(TO_CHAR(trunc(date_column_timestamp),'DD-MON-YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

So, the `TO_CHAR` returns something like `'11-MAR-2011'`, which then causes `to_date` to fail because the date formats do not match.

The same problem exists in your `select` clause. You don't need `to_date` around a `trunc` of a date column.